# Picking the Latest Version from the variable in power-shell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to fetch the latest version in the version variable as shown below using PowerShell script/command

```
PS C:>Write-Host $Version

@{Version=1.0} @{Version=1.0.3} @{Version=1.1} @{Version=1.10.2} @{Version=1.10.3} @{Version=1.10.5} @{Version=1.10.8} @{Version=1.10.9} @{Version=1.2} @{Version
=1.3} @{Version=1.4} @{Version=1.7} @{Version=1.8} @{Version=1.9} @{Version=1.9.1} @{Version=1.9.2} @{Version=1.9.3} @{Version=1.9.5}
```

Using PowerShell how do I compare the decimal valued versions in above array variable and fetch the latest version?

In this case the latest version available is "1.10.9", and in future if there is a new version added to the list say "1.10.10" or "1.11" my script should be able to pick that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enumerate and convert your strings properties to actual version types using `[Version[]]`. Then you can use [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7) to get the maximum and eventually convert that back to a string:

```
([Version[]]$Version.Version | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum.ToString()
```

Comment: This worked for me iRon thank you.

# Script.ps1:
Write-Host "-VersionList : "$Version
$Latest_Version = ([Version[]]$Version.Version | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum.ToString()
Write-Host "-Latest Version : "$Latest_Version
#################
# Result:
-VersionList  : @{Version=1.0} @{Version=1.0.3} @{Version=1.1} @{Version=1.10.2} @{Version=1.10.3} @{Version=1.10.5} @{Version=1.10.8} @{Version=1.10.9} @{Version=1.2} @{Version =1.3} @{Version=1.4} @{Version=1.7} @{Version=1.8} @{Version=1.9} @{Version=1.9.1} @{Version=1.9.2} @{Version=1.9.3} @{Version=1.9.5}
-Latest Version : 1.10.9